# fnumber.toFixed(2) does not always truncate the value to two decimal points

Tags: javascript

What can be done to prevent numbers like this appearing in my output?

Here is my javascript code.

```
$("#TaskListing table tr td#Begin input").each(function (index, element) {           
  var theRow = $(element).parent().parent();
  var thePercent = $(theRow).children("tr td#Percent:first");
  currentvalue = $(theRow).data("millisecs");
  fnumber = currentvalue / totalTimeMs;
  thePercent.text( 100 * fnumber.toFixed(2));
});
```

I thought that using **fnumber.toFixed(2)** would prevent values like this (**28.0000000000004** ) from appearing but yet they appear from time to time.

[image]

Comment: Just use `parseInt(fnumber*100)` instead of `100 * fnumber.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Actually, it should be `(100 * fnumber).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: type `console.log(0.28 * 100)` to see why

Comment: @Xufox `(100 * fnumber).toFixed(2)` would give `28.00` - `(100 * fnumber).toFixed(0)` would give `28`

Comment: @JaromandaX The title suggests, that’s what he wants.

Comment: true, but the code suggests he doesn't want any decimal places - no complaints over 23, 49 in the image - if he wanted 2 decimal places, he'd be asking why they aren't 23.00 49.00 ... if you truncate a value to two decimal places and multiply it by 100, clearly you don't want decimals :p

Comment: So, in the code I've already calculated the sum of milliseconds across all rows. So, the fnumber would end up being a fraction less than 1.00. It's possible to have a value something like 0.2########## , I only care about two decimal places so I used fnumber.toFixed(2) . This works most of the time but I'm sure there is a strange fraction that it probably has a difficult time converting to just 0.2# ; maybe produces 0.2###### . Then I multiply by 100 to present the value as a percentage.

Comment: var tempstr = 100 * fnumber.toFixed(2) ;  I used console.log() to print this out. For the odd cases that show up, it fails to reduce it to two decimal places. current:10500 total:18500 fnum:0.5675675(repeats)  text:56.9999999999999 - I expected to see "57"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to use toFixed like this.

```
thePercent.text( (100 * fnumber).toFixed(2) );
```

You want to perform the calculation first then send it to the toFixed() method

Comment: toFixed() Will always output to 2 decimal places, if you do not want a decimal value you can use Math.round()

Codepen showing example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJGRpy

Comment: thePercent.text( (100 * fnumber).toFixed(2));   // This Works!  @Web Dev Guy, I'm not sure if you mistyped your solution. Don't you need to have parens for the text function?  thePercent.text( SOMEVALUE ) ?

Comment: Web Dev Guy's answer results in error.  jquery-3.1.1.js:3846 jQuery.Deferred exception: thePercent.text(...).toFixed is not a function TypeError: thePercent.text(...).toFixed is not a function

Comment: `thePercent.text( (100 * fnumber).toFixed(2));` Try that

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use  thePercent.text(  (100 * fnumber).toFixed(2) );

Not sure what the issue is with the other way of doing it, maybe it's a problem with .toFixed() for values that can't be expressed without using a repeating fraction.

Comment: It's because thePercent variable in `var thePercent = $(theRow).children("tr td#Percent:first");` is a jquery object. So the `.toFixed(2)` javascript function cant be attached to it using the text method. so it had to be put inside the text() jquery method. Glad I could help you :)